# Selenium driver.Title returning different values C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

In my program I have the driver click into a page and get its title and put it in a string. In debug I see that driver.Title is the title of the new page, but the string contains the title of the previous page. How can I fix this and make the second page titled be assigned to the string?

```
//Title == "Supreme"
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/shop/all");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='container']/article[" + num.ToString() + "]/div/a/img")).Click();
//title of this page should be Supreme: Supreme®/Schott® Shearling Bomber - Lime Green

string title = driver.Title;
//returns first title and not title of new page
```

Comment: you need to wait for the page to be loaded or use a conditional wait for the title like @Guy suggested.

Comment: The root problem is that you are clicking on a <img> element. If you do this, Selenium will immediately execute the next line of code at which point the next page is not loaded yet and you get weird results. If you can click on an <a> element, then Selenium will by default wait until the page is completely loaded before executing the next line of code.

Comment: @HappyBird Hi I've removed the /img from my xpath but it doesn't appear my program is waiting. I can see it navigate to the next page but now driver.Title = Supreme (the first page title) in my debug, and my string title = null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be timing issue, that's why you see the correct value in slower debug but not when you run the script. You can use explicit wait with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) `TitleIs` or `TitleContains` to wait for the correct title

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TitleIs("Supreme: Supreme®/Schott® Shearling Bomber - Lime Green"));
// or
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TitleContains("Shearling Bomber - Lime Green"));
```

This will wait up to 10 seconds for the condition you gave. If the title has changed it will continue immediately, if not you will get `TimeoutException`.

Comment: I've applied the titleContains block in my program but now it is showing my  string contains null, and doesn't appear to be waiting at all

Comment: driver.Title is the correct value in the debug as well

Comment: nevermind i got it working after restarting vs, thank you!